# FFMPEG wrong duration when using amix filter

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

I am trying to add background music to a video with an existing audio-track. I settled for the amix filter, since other filters seemed to cause a delayed audio track. So far everything is working as intended, however the output video is cut off at 11:34min. Which is 3 seconds shorter than the input video. I already tried to increase the length of the input video by e.g. 5 seconds, which still leads to the same output length of 11:34min. Here is the exact command I am using:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i bg_music.wav -filter_complex "[0:a]volume=1.5[a0];[1:a]volume=0.2[a1];[a0][a1]amix=duration=shortest[a]" -map 0:v -map [a] -c:v copy -c:a aac -ar 22050 out.mp4
```

And this is the output I am getting. In this call the video has a length of 11:42min and the audio a length of 36:59min. I am running macOS Catalina 10.15.3:

````
  built with Apple clang version 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.17)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/4.2.2_2 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-ffplay --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libbluray --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-librubberband --enable-libsnappy --enable-libtesseract --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librtmp --enable-libspeex --enable-libsoxr --enable-videotoolbox --disable-libjack --disable-indev=jack
  libavutil      56. 31.100 / 56. 31.100
  libavcodec     58. 54.100 / 58. 54.100
  libavformat    58. 29.100 / 58. 29.100
  libavdevice    58.  8.100 / 58.  8.100
  libavfilter     7. 57.100 /  7. 57.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  5.100 /  5.  5.100
  libswresample   3.  5.100 /  3.  5.100
  libpostproc    55.  5.100 / 55.  5.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'video.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.29.100
  Duration: 00:11:42.14, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 9182 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080, 9196 kb/s, 4.89 fps, 2.92 tbr, 15360 tbn, 120 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 22050 Hz, stereo, fltp, 100 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #1.0 : stereo
Input #1, wav, from 'bg_music.wav':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Adobe Audition 13.0 (Macintosh)
    date            : 2020-02-28
    creation_time   : 15:49:40
    time_reference  : 0
  Duration: 00:36:58.57, bitrate: 2822 kb/s
    Stream #1:0: Audio: pcm_f32le ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 44100 Hz, stereo, flt, 2822 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:1 (aac) -> volume
  Stream #1:0 (pcm_f32le) -> volume
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  amix -> Stream #0:1 (aac)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
Output #0, mp4, to 'out.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.29.100
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080, q=2-31, 9196 kb/s, 4.89 fps, 2.92 tbr, 15360 tbn, 15360 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 22050 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.54.100 aac
frame= 3392 fps=510 q=-1.0 Lsize=  789403kB time=00:11:33.46 bitrate=9325.3kbits/s speed= 104x
video:778257kB audio:11032kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.014279%
[aac @ 0x7fe32d00e800] Qavg: 333.046```
````

Comment: How is the video file generated?

Comment: The video file is generated using ffmpeg aswell. First a .png and a .wav (mono) is combined to a single mp4-file (stereo) using the following command: `ffmpeg -i pic.png -i audio.wav -r 60 -pix_fmt yuv420p -vf scale=1920:1080 -vb 50M -c:a aac -c:v libx264 -ac 2 -ar 22050 out.mp4`
These mp4-files are then combined using `concat` and `-c copy`.

Comment: @Gyan I tried a couple of other things, mostly tinkering with the input files such as changing codecs etc. Unfortunately I am not sure what to do anymore and this is quite a blocker for me. I would be happy to provide some additional information/console outputs or some sample footage. Or is there maybe a filter more suitable for adding music to a video with existing audio? Thank you!

Comment: Sample footage is good.